# How to change ajax url request dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

Hello guys i have this problem, how can i change the url for the ajax request dynamically with onclick button what i want to do is change the 'webdav' in the ajax url to data[0][j].name retrieved in the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: 'json',
     url: "{{ path('user_files',{'oc': 'webdav'}) }}",
     data: {
         restUrl : "/external-api-url/",
         method: 'POST',
         params: {
             action: "getFiles"
         }
     },
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                /*console.info(data[1][0]);*/
                var tabl1 = $('#datatable').children();
                var tmp = "{{ path('user_files',{'oc':'chaine'}) }}";
                  for(var j=1;j<data[0].length;j++){


                    tabl1.append( "<tr><div><td></td><a><td id='aa"+j+"' onClick='document.location.href=\""+tmp.replace('chaine', data[0][j].name)+"\"' style=\"cursor:pointer;\">"+data[0][j].name+"</td></a><td>"+data[0][j].size+
                      "</td><td>"+data[0][j].lastmodified+"</td><td></td></div></tr>" );
                  }
                  for(var j=0;j<data[1].length;j++){

                    tabl1.append( "<tr><td></td><a><td>"+data[1][j].name+"</td></a><td>"+data[1][j].contentlenght+
                      "</td><td>"+data[1][j].lastmodified+"</td><td></td></tr>" );
                  }
                  var a=document.getElementById('aa1');

                //alert(a.innerText)

               }

 });

});
```

Comment: you can assign `{{ path('user_files',{'oc': 'webdav'}) }}` to a variable and then based on your logic update that variable dynamically using JS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend You to use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).
You can decouple the JS from twig template.

Then, for example, You can create "URL generators" for all your routers that you may need to use.

```
function ajaxJsonUrlGenerator(commandName) {
    return function(options) {
        options = JSON.stringify(options);
        return Routing.generate(locale+'__RG__vplanning_ajax_json', { 'command': commandName, 'options': options});
    };
}
```

In my case I describe all options through routing and no need more to describe it through ajax function directly, but in your case your can use something like this:

```
var youroption = 'webdav';
function getUrl(youroption) {
    return Routing.generate('user_files',{'oc': youroption});
}
function createPost(url) {
     return $.post(
          url,
          {
             restUrl : "/external-api-url/",
             method: 'POST',
             params: {
                     action: "getFiles"
                    }
           },
          'json'
      )
}
$("#yourSubmitButton").on('click', function() {
      var mypost = createPost(getUrl(youroption));
      mypost.done(function(data){
      ....yourcode...;
      ...yourcode...;
      youroption = data[0][j].name;
      })
}
```

Where data[0][j].name is your correct option name. So, you can pass to **youroption** each time different option.